# Need guidance in making mysql database model for basic chat web application

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to build a basic chat application which will use PHP and MySQL.
I have designed a model so far. please have a look.

[image]

Now I have some questions.
let me show quickly what I want to achieve please check this image -

[image]

So in this image, there is a listing of all the conversations of the current user. I am also trying to build something similar.
so the question is, is this(above database design) design will be effective or it could be better? if yes then how?

and please tell am i using correct relationships in my tables?

I am new at the SQL. any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

p.s. I have forgotten to add timestamps in the conversations and messages table. that I will add later so, I can sort my messages order_by timestamp.

Comment: No need for the user_has_conversations table. Build the relationship directly between users and conversations since there are two keys in conversions that would link back to users. You would have to have two rows in user_has_conversations in your current design.

Comment: To get a list of a user's conversations, your where would be ```user_id = user_one OR user_id = user_two```

Comment: @SloanThrasher. Thank you for the reply. i am bit confused, building relationship between users and conversations.. what kind of relations ship it will be? many-to-many ? right now i think it is many-to-many.

Comment: Can the same 2 users be part of more than one conversation? Do you need to support conversations between more than 2 users?

Comment: `user_one` and `user_two` in `conversations` are redundant. You already model which user has a conversation with whom via `user_has_conversations` (any user in `user_has_conversations` that appears for a certain `conversation_id` is part of that conversation). Other than that it looks fine I think.

Comment: @chabzjo thank you for reply. In this design I haven't thought about group chat( more than 2 users) . But if  you have any solution for this let us know.

Comment: @sticky bit. Thank you for the reply. Yes. You are right . I didn't think about this. So my conversation table will have only `id` field??

Comment: Yes, if you don't need any more information in it.

Comment: @sticky bit Thank you very much. It was helpful.

Comment: how could you decide who is sender of a message? user1 or user2 send the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove conversations.user_one and conversations.user_two. It's redundant since you're already storing that information in users_has_conversation.

(Don't forget to add timestamps to store the sequence of messages!)

Comment: So my conversations table will have only one column called id?

Comment: For now. But I'm guessing you'll want to eventually add some calculated columns to optimize your code if you're getting too much traffic. Like, for example the ID of the last message (so you don't have to do a join every time), or the amalgamation of pictures like we see in your screenshot.